# Convert MIkrotik Datetime to Mysql Date Time

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have array where one of the key is datetime , and its value format looks like this :

```
dec/10/2017 01:50:33
```

and my problem is , when i insert to database , the value changes become like :

```
0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

Could you help me to fix that ?? how to fix that in php, Thanks

Comment: What techniques have you attempted to convert the date string?  Your question is incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str_replace` and `date` and `strtotime` method

**Easy and Simple like this:**

```
   $date = 'dec/10/2017 01:50:33';
   $formatedDate = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
   echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($formatedDate));
```

**Output:**

```
  2017-12-10 01:50:33
```

Comment: thanks bro , it's worked for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to do if you just reformat the string so that PHP's strtotime function knows what to do with it:

```
<?php

// Original string
$str = "dec/10/2017 01:50:33";

// Split the date from the time
$parts = explode(' ', $str);

// Split up the date
$date_parts = explode( '/', $parts[0] );

// Reassemble so strtotime works with a recognized format
$time = strtotime( $date_parts[0] . ' ' . $date_parts[1] . ', ' . $date_parts[2] . ' ' . $parts[1] );

// Format date for MySQL
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);

// 2017-12-10 01:50:33
```

Comment: thanks bro for help it's worked but it's to complex